# Rails Form has blank fields. I need to allow this and save all the submitted data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

Ho there, I have a form that that create a enw entry in the DB. If the user does not complete the entire form a record is created but none of the data inputted is saved into that record.

I am looking to understand how to permit a create method that accepts not all field will be completed and will just save the fields it has.

Can anyone help?

my controller code looks like this:

```
def create
@wo = WorkOrder.new(workorder_params)
puts "outputting varibles"

if @wo.save

  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
else
  render('new')
end

end


private
def workorder_params
params.require(:wo)
  .permit(

  :work_order_ref,
  :customer_id,
  :customer_contact_name,
  :customer_contact_number,
  :customer_contact_email,
  :delivery_terms_for_order,
  :customer_po_number,
  :sage_call_off_number,
  :order_detail_1,
  :order_detail_2,
  :dt_customer_ordered,
  :dt_customer_required,
  :dt_orig_promise,
  :dt_current_fulfill,
  :sales_order_number,
  :sales_person,
  :customer_address_id,
  :shipping_id

  )
  end
```

Would someone be able to point me the correct direction and give me an example with my code?

The form code is:

```
<%= form_for(:wo, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Name</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:customer_id) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Contact Name</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:customer_contact_name) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Contact Number</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:customer_contact_email) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Delivery Terms for Order</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:delivery_terms_for_order) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer PO Number</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:customer_po_number) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sage Call Off Number</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:sage_call_off_number) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Order Detail 1</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:order_detail_1) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Order Details 2</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:order_detail_2) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Date Customer Ordered</th>
            <td><%= f.date_field(:dt_customer_ordered) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Date Customer Required</th>
            <td><%= f.date_field(:dt_customer_required) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Date Originally Promised</th>
            <td><%= f.date_field(:dt_orig_promise) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Current Fulfilment Date</th>
            <td><%= f.date_field(:dt_current_fulfill) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sales Order Number</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:sales_order_number) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Sales Person</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:sales_person) %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Customer Address</th>
            <td><%= f.text_field(:customer_address_id) %></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <div class="form-buttons">
        <%= submit_tag("Create Work Order") %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Once ammending the code the form posts correctly, but the data doesn't save.. the console output looks like this

```
Started POST "/work_orders/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-03 18:51:54 +0100
Processing by WorkOrdersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V",    "authenticity_token"=>"RSJo7m6eenJNOeF74O/hzfRdG6826XAQgVMGFtYPG/A=", "work_order"=>  {"customer_id
"=>"", "customer_contact_name"=>"joe", "customer_contact_email"=>"6786786786",    "delivery_terms_for_order"=>"", "customer_po_n
umber"=>"", "sage_call_off_number"=>"", "order_detail_1"=>"", "order_detail_2"=>"",   "dt_customer_ordered"=>"", "dt_customer_r
 equired"=>"", "dt_orig_promise"=>"", "dt_current_fulfill"=>"",      "sales_order_number"=>"", "sales_person"=>"",
"customer_address_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Work Order"}
 outputting varibles
 (0.0ms)  begin transaction
 SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "work_orders" ("created_at", "customer_contact_email",    "customer_contact_name", "customer_po_numbe
 r", "delivery_terms_for_order", "order_detail_1", "order_detail_2",    "sage_call_off_number", "sales_order_number", "sales_pers
 on", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-  03 17:51:54.856110"], ["customer_contac
 t_email", "6786786786"], ["customer_contact_name", "joe"], ["customer_po_number", ""],    ["delivery_terms_for_order", ""], ["or
der_detail_1", ""], ["order_detail_2", ""], ["sage_call_off_number", ""],   ["sales_order_number", ""], ["sales_person", ""], [
"updated_at", "2014-08-03 17:51:54.856110"]]
(5.0ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/work_orders
Completed 302 Found in 15ms (ActiveRecord: 7.0ms)
```

with .save! --- ( NO ERRORS SHOWN ON WEB PAGE)

```
Started POST "/work_orders/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-03 19:56:13 +0100
Processing by WorkOrdersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"V",     "authenticity_token"=>"RSJo7m6eenJNOeF74O/hzfRdG6826XAQgVMGFtYPG/A=", "work_order"=>      {"customer_id
"=>"", "customer_contact_name"=>"joe", "customer_contact_email"=>"6786786786",       "delivery_terms_for_order"=>"", "customer_po_n
umber"=>"", "sage_call_off_number"=>"", "order_detail_1"=>"", "order_detail_2"=>"",    "dt_customer_ordered"=>"", "dt_customer_r
equired"=>"", "dt_orig_promise"=>"", "dt_current_fulfill"=>"",       "sales_order_number"=>"", "sales_person"=>"",
"customer_address_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Create Work Order"}
outputting varibles
```

(0.0ms)  begin transaction
    SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "work_orders" ("created_at", "customer_contact_email",     "customer_contact_name", "customer_po_numbe
    r", "delivery_terms_for_order", "order_detail_1", "order_detail_2",       "sage_call_off_number", "sales_order_number", "sales_pers
    on", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-08-     03 18:56:13.821830"], ["customer_contac
    t_email", "6786786786"], ["customer_contact_name", "joe"], ["customer_po_number", ""],       ["delivery_terms_for_order", ""], ["or
    der_detail_1", ""], ["order_detail_2", ""], ["sage_call_off_number", ""],         ["sales_order_number", ""], ["sales_person", ""], [
    "updated_at", "2014-08-03 18:56:13.821830"]]
    (10.0ms)  commit transaction
    Redirected to /work_orders
    Completed 302 Found in 31ms (ActiveRecord: 14.0ms)

```
Started GET "/work_orders" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-08-03 19:56:13 +0100
Processing by WorkOrdersController#index as HTML
WorkOrder Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "work_orders".* FROM "work_orders"
Rendered work_orders/index.html.erb (6.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 8.0ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: Can you show us your `form code`?

Comment: Can you post your `server log` generated?

Comment: I updated my answer.It should work now.

Comment: Do you have any `validations` setup in your `models`? Try `if @wo.save!` instead of `if @wo.save` and tell me any validation errors raised.

Comment: just btw, you should check out simple_form gem

Comment: no validation is being used

Comment: Try changing the name `workorder_params` to `work_order_params` in both `create` method and `workorder_params` method.

Comment: Did my suggestion worked?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct,there is a mistake in your code.Your `workorder_params` method should be like this

```
def workorder_params
  params.require(:work_order).permit(:work_order_ref,:customer_id,:customer_contact_name,
  :customer_contact_number,:customer_contact_email,:delivery_terms_for_order,
  :customer_po_number,:sage_call_off_number,:order_detail_1,:order_detail_2,
  :dt_customer_ordered,:dt_customer_required,:dt_orig_promise,:dt_current_fulfill,
  :sales_order_number,:sales_person,:customer_address_id,:shipping_id)
end
```

Notice `work_order` not `wo`

**Update**

And also,this line in your `form`

```
<%= form_for(:wo, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
```

should be like this

```
<%= form_for(@wo, :url => {:action => 'create'}) do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. When I make that change I get the following error   ActionController::ParameterMissing in WorkOrdersController#create
param is missing or the value is empty: work_order

Extracted source (around line #48):
     
private
  def workorder_params
    params.require(:work_order)
      .permit(
      
      :work_order_ref,

Rails.rootv1
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/work_orders_controller.rb:48:in `workorder_params'
app/controllers/work_orders_controller.rb:22:in `create'
Request

Parameters:

 "wo"=>{"customer_id"=>"",

Comment: I made the changes.. however the reocord doesn't save any data.. the sql insert statment look s ok?

Answer (score 0):

Find out what params are coming into the create method, then make sure that the`def workout_params` actually matches the nested params coming in. Also at that stage you can make sure that the values are correctly being passed through from the form by inspecting the params.

So to recap add the following to the top of your create method

```
puts params
puts workout_params
#or use `binding.pry` if you have pry installed
```

and see what values are coming through.

After you have done this either fix it if you can see whats wrong or add the results to your question.